# mysqlsh (MySQL Shell) - Import/Export without mysql.* tables

Tags: mysql, mysql-shell

I've recently installed the `mysqlsh` binary recommended in the documentation because I'd like to take advantage of its performance.

However, it seems to want access to the `mysql` schema in order to do exports/imports. Is there a way around this? The team managing the database is not inclined to grant this access, even read-only.

The original command was:

```
util.exportTable("xyz_db._abc_table","file://abc_table.txt")
```

and the accompanying error:

```
ERROR: Unable to check privileges for user '*******'@'*.*.%'.
User requires SELECT privilege on mysql.* to obtain 
information about all roles.
```

I'm happy to pick a fight about it (at work), but I want to see if there's anything I'm missing first and hopefully someone here knows! The admin team had never heard of `mysqlsh`